# Rasa NLU installation issue

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu

I had rasa nlu version 0.12.3 installed. I had some issues and uninstalled rasa nlu and other requirements using

```
pip uninstall rasa_nlu
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

Now when I am installing rasa nlu again using `pip install rasa_nlu`

I see below messages in the terminal

```
Error processing line 1 of /Users/uername/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:



     Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored

There are more messages regarding installation and the final message is

    Found existing installation: greenlet 0.4.12
    Cannot uninstall 'greenlet'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

And it turns out that rasa nlu is not installed. I know that the nlu is not installed because when I check the nlu version with below command

```
python -c "import rasa_nlu; print(rasa_nlu.__version__);"
```

I get error

```
Error processing line 1 of /Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.2-py3.6-nspkg.pth:



    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 168, in addpackage
          exec(line)
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 557, in module_from_spec
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

    Remainder of file ignored
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rasa_nlu'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was happening due to a distutils installed project which the `pip install` couldn't uninstall before installation.

So I had to use `--ignore-installed`

In short, below command solved the problem

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed rasa_nlu
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall python package which is part of distutils, you can manually remove the folder from 'site-packages' folder. If it is Anaconda distribution, it will be in following folder. I suggest to cut the folder and paste it somewhere else for the backup purpose.

In windows:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

I'm sure Linux will have similar folder structure.

Following 2 items needs to be removed.

Folder [package version no.]
File - [package>.egg-info]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Rasa's official documentation, Install it with

```
pip3 install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

It will install Rasa X and Rasa. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install rasa-x -U --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

[installation guide](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/installation/)